# What is the relationship among $a, b$ and $c$ for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\left(ax^2+2bxy+cy^2\right)}dx dy=1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, jacobian

> What relationship must hold between the constants $a, b$ and $c$ to make:
> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-\left(\, ax^{2}\ +\ 2bxy\ +\ cy^2\,\right)}\phantom{A\,}{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y = 1
> $$

I am absolutely clueless on how to proceed with this question. I found a solution to this question on [this website](https://quizlet.com/explanations/questions/what-relationship-must-hold-between-the-constants-a-b-and-c-to-make-8417cb4d-164400f1-7930-4836-997e-abed9f805841) but the initial steps where it uses the transformation with the constraints on $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and $\delta$ is not clear to me. Like what was the intuition behind this transformation $?$. I understand that the end result is somewhat similar to the initial assumptions, but how am I supposed to think of this particular transformation in an exam?

I would appreciate any alternate answers/techniques to this question. Explanation(s) to the external linked solution are also welcome.

Edit #1: As mentioned by fellow users in the comments, the link is hidden behind a paywall. Here's the crux of what was given as the solution:

They used the transformation $$s=\alpha x+\beta y$$ $$t=\gamma x+\delta y$$ where $\left(\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma\right)^2=ac-b^2$.

Then they solved for $x$ and $y$ and proceeded with the Jacobian of the transformation and hence the given integral to obtain the required condition.

Comment: The link you passed is not free, so I can't help much. Now, I don't know up to which level of understanding you need but I would regard as unfair if this type of excersisess appeared on an exam. When I took the course of multivariate calculus our cathedra told us that we only had to know the basic transformations (rectangular, cylindrical and spherical coordinates). Otherwise cross your fingers for an enlightenment in the few hours of the exam

Comment: As said above, I can't see it, but it seems like the logical thing to do here would be to look for a rotation that changes your integrand to C$e^{-(AX^2+BY^2)}$ for some constants $A,B,C$. It should be noted that this is only integrable if $A,B\geqslant 0$ which will give conditions. Then this can be easily integrated as a Gaussian, and set to 1 to give you another condition.

Comment: @jcneek See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Integrate in polar coordinates as follows
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\left(ax^2+2bxy+cy^2\right)}dx dy\\
=& \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty
 e^{-r^2\left(a\cos^2t+2b \cos t\sin t+c\sin^2t\right)}rdrdt \\
=& \ \frac12 \int_0^{2\pi} \frac1{a\cos^2t+2b \cos t\sin t+c\sin^2t}dt\\
=& \ \frac12 \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sec^2 t}{a+2b \tan t+c\tan^2t}dt\\
=&\ \frac1{2c} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d(\tan t)}{(\tan t+\frac bc)^2 + \frac{ac-b^2}{c^2}}
= \frac1{c} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{d(\tan t)}{\tan^2 t+ \frac{ac-b^2}{c^2}}\\
=&\ \frac1{\sqrt{ac-b^2}}\tan^{-1}\frac{c\tan t}{\sqrt{ac-b^2}}\bigg|_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}=\frac\pi{\sqrt{ac-b^2}}=1
\end{align}
which leads to $ac-b^2=\pi^2$.

Comment: The last $\pi$ is missing an exponent

Comment: @user170231 thanks, fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Recognise that the integral is proportional to the pdf for a bivariate normal distribution centred on the origin with inverse-of-covariance matrix
$$\mathbf\Sigma^{-1}=2\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{bmatrix},\det\mathbf\Sigma=\frac1{4(ac-b^2)}$$
We require the normalisation $\frac1{2\pi}\frac1{\sqrt{\det\mathbf\Sigma}}$ to be $1$ to match the given integral, which becomes
$$\det\mathbf\Sigma=\frac1{4\pi^2}=\frac1{4(ac-b^2)}\implies\pi^2=ac-b^2$$
Rewriting this as $\pi^2+b^2=ac$ we see that $a$ and $c$ are both positive or both negative. It cannot be the latter since the integral then diverges, so the conditions for the integral to be $1$ are $\pi^2=ac-b^2$ and $a,c>0$.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method is to complete the square for the x-variable as $(x+\frac{b}{a}y)^{2}$
and integrate over $x$, yielding a Gaussian-type integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a((x+\frac{b}{a}y)^2-(\frac{b}{a}y)^2)}dx= \sqrt\frac{\pi}{a}e^{\frac{b^2}{a}y^2}
\end{equation}
Upon inserting the RHS into the y-variable integral, performing a second Gaussian integration, and noticing that convergence is ensured only if $c-\frac{b^2}{a}>0$, yields the result:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\pi}{\sqrt(ac-b^2)}= 1
\end{equation}
Indeed, since $ac=\pi^{2}+b^2$, and since neither $a$ or $c$ can be negative for convergence reasons, both $a$ and $c$ must be simultaneously positive.